# Код не работает в ubuntu, но работает на win

Tags: python, ubuntu, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота для ВК. На win запускается отлично и без проблем. Захотелось установить его на сервер Ubuntu 16.04, но столкнулся с проблемой. Изначально скрипт не захотел открываться, сообщая о

```
"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file my_bot.py on line 23, but no encoding declared"
```

Загуглил, исправил эту проблему добавлением в начало скрипта

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Но теперь проблема следующая:

```
my_bot.py:74: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if body.lower() == 'какая неделя?' or body.lower() == 'неделя':
my_bot.py:77: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif body.lower() == 'пара': #or body.lower() == 'когда пара?' or body.lower() == 'когда пара':
```

И конкретно этому решения я пока, к сожалению, не нашел.

Comment: Для начала определитесь с питоном: второй или третий? Внимательно перепроверьте, каким именно питоном вы запускаете скрипт

Comment: Если ваш скрипт написан для третьего питона, то простой запуск третьим питоном решит все проблемы (даже conding будет не нужен)

Comment: думаю у вас куча коментариев на русском в коде... Попробуйте их убрать или заменить на Simple English.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- Coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: У меня же и так это вставлено в начало кода

Comment: @Витя у тебя `coding` с маленькой, но даже это не главное. `python3` напиши вместо `python`, потому что в *buntu `python` это по-умолчанию python2, который с Юникодом дружит через задницу

Comment: Поменял на python3 и с большой буквы Coding написал, выводит "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character" всё равно

Comment: @Витя как запускаешь? `python3 my_script.py`?

Comment: Вообще, запускал так: python my_bot.py, но когда попробовал как Вы сказали, то вышло следующее:
"
-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file   or directory"

Comment: @Витя `sudo apt install python3` Python3 нужно установить значит

Comment: coding должен быть с маленькой